# Barrier Option pricing and valuation

Tags: finance, economics, actuarial-science

Good day,

> A **reverse knock-out barrier call option** expires worthless if the asset
>   price ever goes above a given barrier level. Calculate the value of this
>   barrier option struck at $K = 3$ with barrier level $B = 9$.
>
> Also, explain why the barrier call option worth less than the vanilla call?
>
> $r=0$

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& S(t=0,\omega) & S(t=1,\omega)^* & S(t=2,\omega)^* &S(t=3,\omega)^* \\ \hline
\omega_1 & 5& 8& 11 &15\\ \hline
\omega_2 & 5& 8& 11 &10\\ \hline
\omega_3 & 5& 8& 7 &10\\ \hline
\omega_4 & 5& 8& 7 &5\\ \hline
\omega_5 & 5& 4& 7 &10\\ \hline
\omega_6 & 5& 4& 7 &5\\ \hline
\omega_7 & 5& 4& 2 &5\\ \hline
\omega_8 & 5& 4& 2 &1\\ \hline
\end{array}

I found risk neutral probabilities for each path and at each node and I think I am correct (hard to go wrong as $r=0$ and no dividends are paid.I calculated the value of a vanilla call option using dynamic programming but Im not quite sure how to approach the Barrier option valuation. Do I simply put the paths with over $9$ to be equal to $0$ and apply dynamic programming again?

The additional question; its worth less as there is a range of values for which the option is worth anything whereas a vanilla option has only a minimum.

Comment: Your explanation "its worth less as there is a range of values for which the option is worth anything whereas a vanilla option has only a minimum."  is incomplete (and not well worded).  You should remark that there is no scenario in which the barrier pays more than than vanilla and that there are scenarios in which the vanilla pays more.  It's odd that none of your paths trigger the barrier unless they trigger it at expiry.  That's not usually the case, but you can exploit it to write the barrier as the difference between two ordinary calls.